# Running Electrum wallet and full node on Windows. How to configure SSL with self-signed certificate

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows, ssl, electrum-server

I have a full node running on Windows 10, I have Electrum wallet installed and I have BTC-RPC-EXPLORER set up.

The problem I have is that I can find no clear guide to setting up and installing a certificate so SSL can be used on the Electrum server port 50002 so everything can actually talk to each other.

I installed just about everything 'out of the box' and expected it to all work...

I guess I need to generate a certificate and then put files etc. in certain places. This must be something that most installations have done - but not documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost deleted the question - but the answer maybe of use to others.

I have Bitcoin Core running as a Windows app, I have Electrum wallet running as a Windows app, but have Electrum server running under node... and btc-rpc-explorer running as a stand alone EXE -- all on the same PC.

The problem was that I had forgotten to start the Electrum server!

So this issue is fixed, but I have a load more (the explorer isn't showing wallet balances - it says 'no transactions') -- but I'll post these in the best place I can find when I run out of ideas again...

Comment: Seeing a load of recent edits, I think an admin has far too much time on their hands... this is dangerous... people looking for things to do, that don't need doing.